# Mongo issue trying to get data base on following condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to get count of emails on daily bases, on condition of email status Send and Failed.

```
db.emails.aggregate([
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":{
            "$dateToString":{
               "format":"%Y-%m-%d",
               "date":"$createdAt"
            },
            {
               "status":"$sEmailStatus"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this query:

Your `_id` into `$group` is bad formatted so you can try this way (you were almost there).

The trick here is to group by date parsing to string and getting only the day (i.e. group by the day) and then using `$sum` with `$cond`. If the status is "Send" is added 1 into `sent`. If it is "Failed" then is added into `failed`.

And last a `$project` stage to get the day into field `date` and not inside `_id`. By the way this is optional.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "id": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "date": "$createdAt",
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
          }
        }
      },
      "sent": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$sEmailStatus",
                "Send"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "failed": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$sEmailStatus",
                "Failed"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "date": "$_id.id",
      "sent": 1,
      "failed": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GqQIp7AEHYz)

Also [another approach](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_LnDgYPITxA) is to using `$size` and `$filter`. But filter twice the array I assume is worst than sum into group directly.

Comment: i want to count mail on daily bases with condition email status Send and Failed

Comment: So [this one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TzBrBidBIbb) using `$sum`?

Comment: it is working but both counts failed count and sent count to have to come under the same date like

date: 2023-01-02
sent:4,
failed:0

date:2023-01-03,
sent-0,
failed:4